# PDO returning nothing on a different web server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

this problem has been driving me crazy for the past few days. I made a DB Wrapper to connect and interact with my mysql database and all works fine on my localhost running PHP `5.4.12` however when I moved it over to my VPS (currently hosting an xenforo forum) in a `/forums` directory, as soon as the first query hits, it kills the rest of the page. On my localhost, the queries run and the content is shown. On the VPS, once the page hits the query it stops loading the rest of the page and leaves it blank.

Here's my DB.php:

```
class DB{
private static $_instance = null;
private $_pdo,
        $_query,
        $_error = false,
        $_results,
        $_count = 0;

private function __construct(){
    try{
        $this->_pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='. Config::get('mysql/host') .';dbname=' . Config::get('mysql/db'), Config::get('mysql/username'), Config::get('mysql/password'));
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance(){
    if(!isset(self::$_instance)){
        self::$_instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$_instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()){
    $this->_error = false;
    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)){
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)){
            foreach($params as $param){
                $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }
        if($this->_query->execute()){
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();

        } else{
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()){
    if(count($where) === 3){
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)){
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()){
                return $this;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

public function get($table, $where){
    return $this->action('SELECT *' , $table, $where);
}

public function place($number){
    return $this->results()[$number];
}

public function results(){
    return $this->_results;
}

public function error(){
    return $this->_error;
}

public function count(){
    return $this->_count;
}

}
```

The thing that is really driving me crazy is there are no errors! I've set `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and still nothing. The PHP version on the VPS is `5.3.3`. If you need anymore information please just ask and I'll edit it in.

Comment: Did you look in your error log? Turn on `display_errors`, as just turning up error_reporting won't tell you much (outside the log) `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`  A blank page in PHP when some output is expected always means "go look in the error log"

Comment: You can't use array dereferencing prior to PHP 5.4. That means you can't `return $this->results()[$number];`  and instead must store the result of `$this->results()` to a variable then access `[$number]` from that variable.

Comment: That's the only thing I spot visually. Your error log will tell you more.

Comment: So if I update PHP on the VPS, it should work?

Comment: or simply remove that method?

Comment: Yes probably.  That's not to say something else could be wrong, missing extensions or whatnot, but if you update to 5.4+ you'll be able to `func()[]` while 5.3 will have a `parse error unexpected [`

Comment: If you want pre 5.4 portability, refactor that method.